# Why my testng.xml file is not showing in the usual manner

Tags: eclipse, appium

Every time I open my xml file, it is not showing in the Notepad style but like in the screenshot, instead. How can i write my code, any remedies?

[image]

Comment: Please see how you should ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if your issue is resolved so accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You are in `Design` tab so you are seeing `xml` file in`tree` structure. Clicking on `Source` tab will resolve your issue. For `xml` file  native editor in eclipse have 2 tabs.

**Design Tab:**

It will show file in `tree` structure so you can drill down from `parent node` to `child nodes`

**Source Tab:**

It will show `xml` as source.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the xml file and select OPEN WITH as Text Editor or XML editor, you will see the correct format.

Comment: I believe OP is asking how to do it inside of Eclipse.

Comment: It will work inside eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

IN Eclipse only ,

1. Right Click on xml file(In workspace you can find your xml )
2. select open with ...
3. select on as  generic text editor(regular)